# Как осуществить полиморфные связи в sql?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Можете подробно расписать код sql для создания полиморфных связей?
К примеру пускай будут 4 таблицы: Ученики, Учителя, Родители, КПП.
Первые три таблицы имеют ID, который может повторятся. Этот ID используется в таблице КПП, но чтобы вывести данные в таблице есть два столбца: ID_Посетителя и Tip_Посетителя, где первый столбец - id из любой привязанной таблицы, а второй - название таблицы из которой берут этот id.

Comment: А каким образом может повторяться  id ученика или родителя? Т. Е. У вас есть два разных ученика с одним id? Вот тут все подробно расписано https://m.habr.com/ru/post/261835/

Comment: Уже сто раз читал этот пост. Одинаковый id может быть у ученика, родителя и учителя.

Comment: Тогда в чем проблема? Приведите ваш код для создания таблицы КПП.

Comment: Creat table KPP ( ID_PEŔSON INTEGER, TIP_PERSON TEXT, ID_STAT INTEGER) Где ID_PERSON - id посетителя, TIP_PERSON -  из какой таблицы берется id, ID_STAT - id статуса(зашел человек в здание или вышел). Но код недописан, т.к. не знаю как связать таблицы STUD, TEACH, PARENT с таблицей KPP.

Comment: Они у вас связаны через id и type.

Comment: Вы опишите вашу задачу. Если просто создать таблицы, то вы ее решили.

Comment: Задача была создать таблицу и связать ее с 3-мя другими с помощью id и tip. Я думал что такое возможно в самом коде sql, но ниже написали что это все делается программно. Вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что вы имеете ввиду под словом связи? Если ForeignKey, то это не удастся. 
Если вы вниматеьлно читали, то должны были увидеть это

> Минусы полиморфных связей
>
> Не всё так идеально, как могло бы показаться на первый взгляд. В силу своей динамической природы полиморфных связей, между полями связуемых таблиц, нельзя проставить связи внешних ключей (foreign key) используя СУБД, а тем более и ограничения (constraints) на изменение или удаление записей. Это, собственно самый большой минус полиморфных связей. Придется, либо писать свои триггеры (процедуры или еще что) для самой СУБД, либо, что чаще делают, переложить работу по синхронизации строк и накладыванию ограничений между таблицами на ORM и язык программирования.
>
> Второй, уже менее значительный минус полиморфных связей состоит в типе сущности. Необходимо как-то описать какой тип, какой таблице принадлежит. Это может быть не очевидно, если например название какой-то таблицы изменилось или если вы задали тип сущности цифрами. Решить эту проблему можно, например создав отдельную таблицу, или прописав в коде проекта, ассоциативный массив с сопоставлением типа и сущности.

Что означает, что на уровне БД таблицы не связаны никак, их связывают программно. Только программа знает, что это поле содержит ссылку на другую сущность, и ORM учитывает это во время составления запроса. Для БД это просто поле.

Но для приведенного вами примера это и не нужно. 
Через КПП у вас проходят люди - выделяете сущность человек и вся ваша проблема решена. Так же это решает еще несколько проблем, например: если учитель и родитель в одном лице (когда ребенок учится в школе где работает его мама), так же нормализует базу вам не надо будет прописывать одинаковые поля в каждой сущности. Пример написал на Java, но суть, думаю, понятна:

```
public class Person{
   Long personId;
   ...
}

public class Student{
   Long studentId;
   Long personId;
   ...
}

public class Teacher{
   Long teacherId;
   Long personId;
   ...
}
```

КПП это одельная сущность от прохода человека через КПП, например так:

```
public class Kpp{
   Long kppId;
   Integer number;
   String name;
   ...
}

public class PassageThroughCheckpoint{
   Long passageId;
   LocalDateTime date;
   Long kppId;
   Long personId;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ну, нашёл на просторах Хабра пост о полиморфных связях(в комментариях выше кинули ссылку), потому и пишу что это связи. К сожалению Java совсем не знаю( Если есть возможность, то переведите в SQL код, пожалуйста

Comment: ForeignKey однозначно работать не будет, это я и сам понимаю, потому и прошу помощи

Comment: я добавил цитату из статьи, на которую вы сослались

Comment: Ааааааа, всё, дошло. Огромное спасибо)